# Should I use weekly or daily returns for modelling FX returns?

Tags: time-series, correlation, autocorrelation, garch, frequency

I am currently modelling Foreingn Exchange returns using a GARCH model. I am simulating returns 1-year forward. Would it be better to use weekly or daily data on Foreign Exchange returns? Weekly data cuts down computation time and can level out some shocks. There are obviously more data points when using daily returns.
I've read that the autocorrelation will be lower using weekly returns. This also shows from some test runs. Why is this the case?

Are there any important arguments that are missing?

Comment: just to clarify: you want to forecast a whole year ahead of time? That's a pretty long way. If you're looking at log returns, that's a pretty big sum of random variables, which will also have a pretty big variance. If you're set on that task, I would probably guess that yearly returns data is best.

Comment: Correct. The problem is that I would only have like 18 yearly returns which would not be enough data to get precise predictions. Next to that, I don't want my data to be too old since data from 30 years ago could differ structurally from recent data.  Hence the model would not reflect the current market.

Comment: Try pretending that you do not the true model *and* the true parameters and see what happens to the forecast variance to get an idea of what the best case scenario is